# Is there a publicly available list of possible exceptions that may come when using an ExtJS JsonReader?

Tags: javascript, extjs, jsonreader

I'm having trouble debugging an issue and looking for more information on the possible sources of error with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See documentation for `Ext.data.DataProxy`'s `exception` event.

Comment: I can't seem to find a publicly accessible version of the documentation on google - do you know of an online location where I can check this out?

Comment: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/ You also should have a copy of this in your ExtJS download.

Comment: Boo went for my eyes. I should have seen this. Thanks :)